# Argument of type 'number | boolean | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm create a `validate` input with `typescript` in Nextjs.

```
interface InputRules {
  required?: boolean
  min?: number
  max?: number
  minLength?: number
  maxLength?: number
}
```

And an `object` contain `methods` to handle:

```
const handleRules = {
  required: (val: string, boo: boolean) => {
    if (boo && !val) return `${label || 'This field'} is required`
    return ''
  },
  minLength: (val: string, len: number) => {
    if (val.length < len)
      return `${label || 'This field'} is must least ${len} character`
    return ''
  },
  maxLength: (val: string, len: number) => {
    if (val.length > len)
      return `${label || 'This field'} cann't have more than ${len} character`
    return ''
  },
  min: (val: number | string, num: number) => {
    if (Number(val) < num)
      return `${label || 'This field'} is must equal or greater than ${num}`
    return ''
  },
  max: (val: string | number, num: number) => {
    if (Number(val) > num)
      return `${label || 'This field'} is must equal or less than ${num}`
    return ''
  }
}
```

When input is blur:

```
const handleBlur = (val: string) => {
  if (rules) {
    let result = ''
    for (const key in rules) {
      result = handleRules[key as keyof typeof handleRules](
        val,
        rules[key as keyof typeof handleRules]
      )
      if (result) {
        setErrorMessage(result)
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `handleRules` object have same key with InputRules. When blur input, I `for in` the `rules` of input and call `methods` same key in `handleRules`.

The 2nd params of all method is `boolean | number`. But I got this:

[image]

The app run good, but the error til exist in code.

**Edit**

`rules` is a `props` of input:

```
interface InputProps {
  type?: 'text' | 'password' | 'number'
  label?: string
  prefix?: JSX.Element | string
  subfix?: JSX.Element | string
  defaultValue?: string
  placeHolder?: string
  passClass?: string
  error?: string
  rules?: InputRules
  disabled?: boolean
  onChange?: (e: any) => void
}
```

The `label` just the name to display of `input`

Comment: Please include `rules` and `label`

Comment: I dont know why `boolean | number` turn to `never`

Comment: You use keyo HandleRules as key for the rules. How come?

Comment: keyof `rules` is same as keyof `handleRules` and I dont have any better idea. @wonderflame

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the type declaration for the rules parameter in your handleBlur function. The rules parameter is defined as InputRules, which is an interface containing optional properties, but in your code, you are treating it as if all the properties are required.

To fix the issue, you can update the type declaration for the rules parameter to allow for optional properties. Here's an updated version of your handleBlur function:

```
    const handleBlur = (val: string) => {
  if (rules) {
    let result = '';
    for (const key in rules) {
      result = handleRules[key as keyof typeof handleRules](
        val,
        rules[key] as boolean | number // Add type assertion here
      );
      if (result) {
        setErrorMessage(result);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

By using rules[key] as boolean | number, you're explicitly stating that the value being passed to handleRules can be either a boolean or a number, which matches the signature of your handleRules methods.

Comment: til error: `Argument of type 'number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'`